# c++ compilation error using #include<algorithm>

Tags: c++, algorithm, compiler-errors

I'm having compilation error whenever i try to compile the programme.

when I try to remove the "sort" function in this programme everything is fine, problem start arising when I use the "sort" function.

Is there any other way to solve this issue or there no way i could use #include ? It's the same when I use the "swap" function.

here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class tropical
{
    public:
    string name;
    int price;
};

bool sortByName(tropical &t1, tropical  &t2); //

void displayfruits(vector<tropical> fruitlist) 
{
    cout << "Name \t\tPrice" << endl << "==========\t=====" << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) //displays all fruits' names and prices
    {
        cout << fruitlist[i].name << "  \t" << fruitlist[i].price << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int sortchoice; 
    string searchfruit; 


    string fruitname[] = {"Avocado", "Papaya", "Grapefruit", "Pineapple", "Jackfruit", "Orange", "Honeydew", "Mangosteen", "Banana", "Durian"};
    int fruitprice[] = {1, 4, 6, 2, 10, 3, 9, 7, 5, 8};

    vector<tropical> fruitlist;
    tropical fruit; 
    vector<tropical>::iterator it; 

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
    {
        fruit.name = fruitname[i];
        fruit.price = fruitprice[i];

        fruitlist.push_back(fruit);
    }

    displayfruits(fruitlist); 

        sort (fruitlist.begin(), fruitlist.end(), sortByName); 

    displayfruits(fruitlist); 
}

bool sortByName(tropical &t1, tropical &t2)
{
    return t1.name < t2.name;
}
```

this is error i'm getting

```
     In file included from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/algorithm:63:0,
                         from ..\src\tutorial 3 - Constants and Formatting Decimals.cpp:2:
        c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h: In function '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<tropical*, std::vector<tropical> >, _Tp = tropical, _Compare = bool (*)(tropical&, tropical&)]':
        c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2265:78:   instantiated from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<tropical*, std::vector<tropical> >, _Compare = bool (*)(tropical&, tropical&)]'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2306:62:   instantiated from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<tropical*, std::vector<tropical> >, _Size = int, _Compare = bool (*)(tropical&, tropical&)]'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:5445:4:   instantiated from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<tropical*, std::vector<tropical> >, _Compare = bool (*)(tropical&, tropical&)]'
..\src\tutorial 3 - Constants and Formatting Decimals.cpp:56:61:   instantiated from here
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2233:4: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'tropical&' from expression of type 'const tropical'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2236:4: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'tropical&' from expression of type 'const tropical'
```

I've tried running this example which i've found on the web (the source attached below) and i'm facing the same problem? why is this so?

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/242984/sorting-multiple-array-containers-with-related-elements#post1064721

Comment: Compiles fine on my compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include string header file:

```
#include <string>
```

Also make const reference to tripical

```
bool sortByName(const tropical &t1, const  tropical  &t2);
```

See [live](http://ideone.com/Eikbr4) sample.

Comment: yup, it's already included but i still have problem doing a compilation.

Comment: sorry because i'm new to C++ so pardon my silly question. why is there a need to make a const reference?

Comment: @user2900611 Because that's what the sort() function expects. sort() will pass const references to the comparision function. So sortByName  should not be able to modify the data being compared - if it did, the order would end up being unpredicable.

Comment: @nos sorry just another question.. it's possible to separate this example into .h and .cpp right.. because when i separate the code they would actually state that sort could not be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You must modify both the declaration and definition of function sortByName to receive const references to tropical, like so:

```
bool sortByName(const tropical &t1, const tropical &t2); //Prototype (declaration)


bool sortByName(const tropical &t1, const tropical &t2)  //definition
{
    return t1.name < t2.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define args of sortByName as const.

```
// Declaration
bool sortByName(const tropical t1, const tropical t2);

// Implementation
bool sortByName(const tropical t1, const tropical t2)
{
    return t1.name < t2.name;
}
```

Comment: Try to change declaration too: bool sortByName(const tropical t1, const tropical t2);